# Static page for desktop or mobile

Tags: mobile, frontpage

Can you automatically change to a static page if access to the site is via mobile device?

Currently my homepage is static and use components that do not work properly with mobile devices but are are necessary for the desktop version. I want to create another static page that will be displayed in the case of mobile devices.

I have tried using the code WP Moving but I could not.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: There is no reliable way server side to do this. You are going to serve the wrong page to some users no matter what you try. Your whole project relies on client side processes which is never reliable. You need to look into `wp_is_mobile()` or some other mobile switchers, but be warned, as I said, these relies on client side processes and **WILL** fail for some users which will show incorrect data to them

Comment: Thk, i use this:<?php if ( wp_is_mobile() && is_front_page() ) {
    wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com', 301 ); exit;
} ?>

Answer (score 1):

I used this:

```
<?php if ( wp_is_mobile() && is_front_page() ) {
    wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com', 301 ); exit;
} ?>
```

in `header.php` of theme.

Comment: Answer seems to work on Safari but not firefox mobile...(ios each case) strange